# Guess my number c++ while loop inside a loop

Tags: c++

I have this simple guess my number code as I am learning C++. As you can see it selects a random number and lets the user guess it and records the number of tries.

```
int main(){
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed number generator

   int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
   int tries = 0;
   int guess;

   cout << "\tWelcome to Guess my Number\n\n";
   do{
    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    ++tries;

    if (guess > secretNumber){
        cout << "Too high\n";
    } else if (guess < secretNumber){
        cout << "Too low \n";
    } else {
        cout << "You got it :) in " << tries << " tries \n\n";
    }
   } while(guess != secretNumber);
}
```

While this is working correctly, I also want user to have only 5 tries. I can think of adding another `else if` statement to ensure that `(tries < 6)`.

OR

I can create another while loop inside `do` and ensure that `(tries < 6)`.

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: `while(guess != secretNumber && tries < 5)` ...

Answer (score 4):

you can add a condition to your `do-while-loop`

```
int main(){
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed number generator

   int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
   int tries = 0;
   int guess;

   cout << "\tWelcome to Guess my Number\n\n";
   do{
    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    ++tries;

    if (guess > secretNumber){
        cout << "Too high\n";
    } else if (guess < secretNumber){
        cout << "Too low \n";
    } else {
        cout << "You got it :) in " << tries << " tries \n\n";
    }
   } while((guess != secretNumber) && (tries < 6));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a for loop and break on the correct answer:

```
int main(){
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed number generator

   int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;

   cout << "\tWelcome to Guess my Number\n\n";
   for ( int tries = 1; tries < 6; tries++ ) {
    int guess;
    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;

    if (guess > secretNumber){
        cout << "Too high\n";
    } else if (guess < secretNumber){
        cout << "Too low \n";
    } else {
        cout << "You got it :) in " << tries << " tries \n\n";
        break;
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: basically i like your solution much more then mine^^

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is the best approach. As you said there are 2 possibilities either add condition in while

```
while(guess != secretNumber && tries < 6);
```

or you can go with

```
else if(tries > 5)
{
    cout << "You are out of tries, better luck next time ;) \n"
    break;
}
```

I would prefer the one with adding condition to while. But this is my personal opinion. I meet programmer that wants to do the else if and try to keep loop condition relatively simple. With more complex if/boolean statements you can extract a function with proper name. In your case it can be done like this

```
 bool isEndGame(int guess, int secretNumber, int tries)
 {
     return (guess != secretNumber) && (tries < 6);
 }

 int main()
 {
   srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed number generator

   int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
   int tries = 0;
   int guess;

   cout << "\tWelcome to Guess my Number\n\n";
   do{
    cout << "Enter a guess: ";
    cin >> guess;
    ++tries;

    if (guess > secretNumber){
        cout << "Too high\n";
    } else if (guess < secretNumber){
        cout << "Too low \n";
    } else {
        cout << "You got it :) in " << tries << " tries \n\n";
    }
   } while (isEndGame(guess, secretNumber, tries));
}
```

In my opinion the last one is the best choice. You don't need to think about condition and other programmers can clearly now what it means.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I posted a reply below yours with another question. I would appreciate if you could take a quick look.

Comment: consider not using an extra function to verify your condition... it confuses, makes your code a bit less readable and maybe a little more error prone

Comment: @skratchi.at I totally disagree with your comment. Maybe in this simple case it is not needed, but with just little bit more complex conditions it is necessary for other programmers to understand code. Remember that when you work in company someone will read your code. Also imagine process of code review, no one will allow some long and complex if conditions to just lay around.

Comment: i work in such a company^^ countless code reviews later, i consider comments to explain my condition, if the condition does not explain itself. as short as your function name, would be a short comment and so nobody has to lookup your function, what it really does.

Comment: also consider more complex data structures... you have to consider on every call, to be by-value or by-reference and also add const everywhere, to do not manipulate your data in such a function. next and much more important point is, if you have a multi threaded program, you have to consider thread safety with every function call. with thousands of condition on a larger program, a endless task. simple point of failure for a race condition to happen and therefor undebuggable...

Comment: and there for i strongly advice against using your structure and simply use a comment. this is what comments are for. following KISS - keep it short and simple!

Answer (score 0):

I just did some "trial and error" and also added another loop to "play again". Here's the code.

```
int main(){
   char again = 'y';
   do{
       srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // seed number generator
       int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;
       int tries = 0;
       int guess;

       cout << "\tWelcome to Guess my Number\n\n";
       do{
        cout << "Enter a guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        ++tries;

        if (guess > secretNumber){
            cout << "Too high\n";
        } else if (guess < secretNumber){
            cout << "Too low \n";
        } else {
            cout << "You got it :) in " << tries << " tries \n\n";
        }
       } while((guess != secretNumber) && (tries < 6));
        cout << "Too many tries \n\n";
        cout << "Start again?: ";
        cin >> again;
   } while(again == 'y');
 }
```

I am an advocate of optimizing the code as much as possible to make it faster and use less system resources. Can someone please review if I can tweak it further to optimize it?

Comment: That's a completely bogus concern. How slow do you think computers are?  The first concern for any programmer is to make sure that your code is clear and understandable. Human resources cost **much** more than computer resources, so think about the people looking at your code, not the computers running it.

Comment: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"  -- DonaldKnuth. In case of that simple program and learning C++ it does not make sense to optimize this code. Better learn about compiling in release mode with compiler optimization turned on.

Comment: Looks like "Too many tries" comes up even if you get it right the first try.

Comment: optimizing a code with 50 lines of code, make little to no sense. you normally optimize code, when you experience problems with execution time or something and not when you feel like it. but if you still feel like it, start optimizing on algorithmic level and then dive into your implementation.

Comment: No particular value in optimising that code for performance or resource usage.   Focus on getting ti behaving right, which it doesn't really do.  For example, take the call of `srand()` out of the loop.   If the user is pretty quick (or pipes input to the program) the secret number will probably be repeated.

Comment: You should only call `srand` once not every time round your loop.